# How to Replace attr value from another attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to know, how can i replace style width value from another attr(rel) with jQuery, example:

Example: `<span rel="40"></span>`

i need this: `<span rel="" style="width: 40%"></span>`

with jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#mySpan').css('width', $('#mySpan').attr('rel') + "%");` should work.
But for this solution, you have to add `id="mySpan"` to your span-Tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot worked fine, Now how can i add animation and set time?

Comment: You want to change the width from its previous with an animation?

Comment: `$('#mySpan').animate({width: $('#mySpan').attr('rel') + "%"}, 2000);` should work, 2000 is the time it takes

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
$('span[rel]').each(function() {
    var span = $(this);
    span.css('width', span.attr('rel') + '%');
});
```

This will get all the `<span>`s that have a `rel` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I am using id selector to get the span you want.

```
var this_span = $('#theSpan')
this_span.css('width',this_span.attr('rel')+'%')
```